# Multiple solutions for same number of combinations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can we have distinct pairs of integers, say (n,r) and (N,R) such that number of combinations for each pair ( first integer is higher) has the same numerical value ? 
C(n,r) = C(N,R)

Answer (score 0):

An example: $C(4 , 2)=C(6,1)$.